# Typescript or Angular5 disable button using Class name

Tags: typescript, angular5

I want to disable button using class name. My button is rendering dynamically with class name and it doesn't have id. How can I disable button using class name?

Below HTMLInputElement is not working with class name.

```
(<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementByClassName("class-name")).disabled = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("k-dialog-buttongroup")[0].disabled = true;

(<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("id")).disabled = true;
```

This fix is relating to my previous post :)

[angular 4 Kendo dialog disable action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866322/angular-4-kendo-dialog-disable-action-button)

Comment: Are these buttons all in a component, or just scattered all over the application?

Comment: You would disable and enable the button using angular's bindings rather than selecting it via DOM methods

Comment: This fix is relating to my previous post :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866322/angular-4-kendo-dialog-disable-action-button

Comment: So you already have an answer to the other question. Just put the disabled as described in the answer to the button (which you didn't show in your question)

Comment: No, that doesn't have answer. That's why I'm trying to fix another way

Comment: OK. Maybe consider to delete this question, edit the other one and make it a good question that includes all details needed - for example the button you want to disable... I'm sure someone answers then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            (<HTMLElement>x[i]).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
```

This code is selecting all buttons with css class "btn" and setting disabled attribute.